# Mulesoft 3.8 | Error running the application | An internal error occurred during: "<projectname>" | org.eclipse.core.jobs

Tags: anypoint-studio, mulesoft

I am getting below error while running the Mule 3.8 project:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
at org.mule.tooling.maven.ui.launch.MavenDeploymentStrategy.findFile(MavenDeploymentStrategy.java:123)
at org.mule.tooling.maven.ui.launch.MavenDeploymentStrategy.getResultingZipFile(MavenDeploymentStrategy.java:116)
at org.mule.tooling.maven.ui.launch.MavenDeploymentStrategy.packageZipFile(MavenDeploymentStrategy.java:104)
at org.mule.tooling.maven.ui.launch.MavenDeploymentStrategy.deployToEmbeddedInstance(MavenDeploymentStrategy.java:68)
at org.mule.tooling.runtime.launch.MuleRuntimeLaunchDelegate.deployProjects(MuleRuntimeLaunchDelegate.java:608)
at org.mule.tooling.runtime.launch.MuleRuntimeLaunchDelegate.performLegacyDeployment(MuleRuntimeLaunchDelegate.java:435)
at org.mule.tooling.runtime.launch.MuleRuntimeLaunchDelegate.launch(MuleRuntimeLaunchDelegate.java:327)
at org.eclipse.debug.internal.core.LaunchConfiguration.launch(LaunchConfiguration.java:885)
at org.eclipse.debug.internal.core.LaunchConfiguration.launch(LaunchConfiguration.java:739)
at org.eclipse.debug.internal.ui.DebugUIPlugin.buildAndLaunch(DebugUIPlugin.java:1039)
at org.eclipse.debug.internal.ui.DebugUIPlugin$8.run(DebugUIPlugin.java:1256)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:56)
```

and this is from `Plug-in org.eclipse.core.jobs`

Comment: Which version of Anypoint Studio are you using?

Comment: This is the only thing I can find on the internet matching my exact problem. Did you manage to fix this?